# Submit form to another site via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, http

I just learned how to make HTTP requests via POST to a URL. Now, the website that I need to make a POST request to sends you the page without the form and when you click a button it loads the form with JavaScript.

I tried to find the form on the page, but it does not exist.

Is it only possible to fill the form in the main page after that the form has been loaded with JavaScript? How can I fill out the form?

I tried to use the normal POST method, but not working.

Comment: Why is this tagged "java"?

Comment: because i use the URL class in java

Comment: @karim: How the website delivers the form isn't *entirely* meaningful for your purposes.  How the form delivers the POST request back to the website is.  As long as you can duplicate that request, the website probably won't care whether it came from its own form or from your code.  (If it *does*, such as by issuing one-time-use tokens with forms and whatnot, then it means that website specifically *doesn't* want you to do what you're doing, and we can't help with that.)

Comment: @karim You can also try to find the form once it's been dynamically loaded using a browser's development tools (e.g. Firebug or the like).

Comment: i have found the form : http://www.dofus.com/fr/creer-un-compte take a look at it